# Is there a way to execute a dependent task, when the task it depends on completes, but fails in Azure batch?

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have a set of tasks, that when executed successfully trigger a dependent task through the 'withDependsOn' option. The problem that I am facing is that sometimes the task completes but through a failure, and thus does not execute the dependent task. This way the node stays online and my dependent system (which is waiting for the dependent task), does not get its answer. The closest solution that I've gotten was to timeOut the Job after a specific time, but this way the dependent tasks do not get executed and, the system depending on these tasks, does not get notified.

Is there a way to allow 'withDependsOn' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.taskaddparameter.withdependson?view=azure-java-stable) to also work for 'failed' tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [ExitConditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#exitconditions) [ExitCodeMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#exitcodemapping) or ExitCodeRangeMapping with an associated [ExitOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#exitoptions) [DependencyAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#dependencyaction) to specify `Satisfy`.

See the relevant section of the [Task Dependency Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-task-dependencies#dependency-actions).